# How to set up email provider in Strapi 3.0.1v?

Tags: strapi

I use Strapi 3.0.1 version and I try to adjust the reset password for admin. If I understand correctly I need to set up only an email provider. I had read the doc for setting up email provider [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/email.html#configure-your-provider)

I had installed the **strapi-provider-email-nodemailer** and created a file **./config/plugins.js** with

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  email: {
    provider: 'nodemailer',
    providerOptions: {
      host: "smtp.***.***",
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: "***",
        pass: "***",
      }
    },
    settings: {
      defaultFrom: '***',
      defaultReplyTo: '***',
    },
  },
});
```

After that, I navigate to ****/admin/auth/forgot-password* and input admin email and get an error This email is invalid.

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": [{"messages": [{"id": "Auth.form.error.email.invalid"}]}],
  "data": [{"messages": [{"id": "Auth.form.error.email.invalid"}]}]
}
```

Could you please help me to set up an email provider or find a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It works with settings:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  email: {
    provider: "nodemailer",
    providerOptions: {
      nodemailer_default_from: "XXX",
      nodemailer_default_replyto: "XXX",
      host: env('EMAIL_HOST'),
      port: env('EMAIL_PORT', 25),
      password: env('EMAIL_PASSWORD'),
      username: env('EMAIL_USERNAME'),
      authMethod: "SMTP",
    }
  },
});
```